# Wordpress where the "admin_url" is set?

Tags: php, wordpress

basically need to change the value that - admin_url() returns any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This function is defined in **wp-includes/link-template.php**, and it offers a filter:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the url to the admin area.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @since 2.6.0
 *
 * @param string $path Optional path relative to the admin url
 * @return string Admin url link with optional path appended
*/
function admin_url($path = '') {
    $url = site_url('wp-admin/', 'admin');

    if ( !empty($path) && is_string($path) && strpos($path, '..') === false )
        $url .= ltrim($path, '/');

    return apply_filters('admin_url', $url, $path);
}
```

So you can control the output with an own filter function in your themes **functions.php**:

```
add_filter('admin_url', 'my_new_admin_url');

function my_new_admin_url()
{
    // Insert the new URL here:
    return 'http://example.org/boss/';
}
```

Now hope that all plugin authors use this function and not an hard coded path … :)

*Addendum*

Add this line to your .htaccess:

```
Redirect permanent /wp-admin/ http://example.org/new_url/
```

Comment: <blockquote>Now hope that all plugin authors use this function and not an hard coded path</blockquote>

i agree with you. But the hardcoded one can be use when you need to make backward compability

Comment: Even Wordpress doesn't seem to respect the filter - if you move that folder you'll get errors like Warning: require_once(/public_html/wp-admin/includes/bookmark.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/app-admin/includes/admin.php on line 10 (right from the core WP folder)

Comment: The wp-admin filesystem path is NOT meant to be changed. However, the admin URL can be changed and mapped to the internal directory path via a server config directive or filesystem link.