# Wordpress redirect admin URL (wp-admin) to a custom url

Tags: wordpress, apache, admin

I've been looking around to change my admin dashboard url to a custom one.
So instead of :
mywebsite/wp-admin -> mywebsite/newadmin

The answers i found online were pretty old or/and just not working.

So far, i've changed my htaccess by

```
RewriteRule ^newadmin/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

And added the following code to function.php:

To change the admin url to newadmin

```
function custom_admin_url() { 
 $url = home_url('/newadmin');
 return $url; 
}
add_filter('admin_url', 'custom_admin_url');
```

The result i get:

- when trying to click on the top admin bar, it goes to /newadmin but the page is not found
- when i try to access /wp-admin directly, it goes to /wp-admin (i would like to disable it)

I guess i just need a way for /newadmin to render the wp-admin folder. And it seems that it should be done in htaccess or wp-config but i can't find a way to make it work.

Any ideas?

So far i tried these :

- [Rename WordPress admin URL wp-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087198/rename-wordpress-admin-url-wp-admin)
- [Wordpress where the "admin_url" is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584706/wordpress-where-the-admin-url-is-set)
- https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/how-to-change-wordpress-admin-url-in-wordpress-without-plugin/
- https://gist.github.com/aaronhuisinga/5cb046ea9ddbf37f0da8